# Flutter web app & firebase : Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: firebase, flutter, import, module

I want to connect firebase to my flutter web app.
I followed all solutions on web, official and advice.

my flutter version : Flutter 2.6.0-12.0.pre.522

I have always this error inside console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

the code inside index.html from build/web :
(my firebase version : 9.21.0)

```
<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "",
   authDomain: "",
   projectId: "",
   storageBucket: "",
   messagingSenderId: "",
   appId: ""
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
</script>
```

the main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

the firebase folder have only an hosting.(numbers).cache

the firebase.json :

```
{"hosting": {
"public": "build/web",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
   "**/.*",
   "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
   {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
   }
]
}
}
```

and my pub spec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
      sdk: flutter
   firebase_core: ^1.8.0
   firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
```

Comment: Are you solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but i solved it by using the following updated method. (I used the latest package.)
It looks like some script tags aren't needed anymore.
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/

The config information is put in

```
Firebase.initializeApp (options: FirebaseOptions(...))
```

on the dart code side.